# Skip a behave step in the step implementation

Tags: python, python-behave

Is there a way to tell behave in a step implementation to skip the current step?

Something like:

```
@given("bla bla bla")
def step():
    skip_current_step()
```

The use case is that I want to check if some additional software is installed. If not, I want the complete scenario to be skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can skip from inside of a step, but you can skip a whole scenario at feature level:

```
def before_feature(context, feature):
    is_software_installed = some_foo_magic()

    if not is_software_installed:
        for scenario in feature.scenarios:
            if depends_on_software(scenario):
                scenario.mark_skipped()
```

`Feature`, `Scenario`, and `ScenarioOutline` all have a `mark_skipped()` method.

Answer (score 14):

Let me improve @Barry's answer:

Basically, what he proposed (i.e. `scenario.mark_skipped()`) is equal to:

```
scenario.skip(require_not_executed=True)
```

To be exact, `mark_skipped()`'s source looks like this:

```
def mark_skipped(self):
    """Marks this scenario (and all its steps) as skipped.
    Note that this method can be called before the scenario is executed.
    """
    self.skip(require_not_executed=True)
    assert self.status == "skipped", "OOPS: scenario.status=%s" % self.status
```

`skip()` is defined like so:

```
def skip(self, reason=None, require_not_executed=False)
```

A few things:

- `require_not_executed=True` means that scenario cannot be skipped if any step has already passed, i.e. `mark_skipped()` in second or later step will throw an Exception and then skip all the steps afterwards, instead of just skipping the further steps
- `skip()` allows to provide a reason for skipping, which is then logged as `WARN`.

Furthermore, `scenario` object is available in context as `context.scenario` (alongside `context.feature`).

Ultimately, simple example:

```
@given("test photos in upload directory")
def step_impl(context):
    if not connection_available():
        context.scenario.skip(reason='internet connection is unavailable')
```

Result:

```
Skipped: skipped
WARNING:behave:SKIP Scenario Retrieving uploaded photo details: internet connection is unavailable
```

Comment: For the benefit of those still on 1.2.4 (like I was until a few minutes ago): the code from behave's codebase which is quoted in this answer is from 1.2.5.

Comment: Is there a way to print the captured logging for skipped scenarios? It seems that warnings only get printed when the scenario fails (i.e. placing an `assert False` after `scenario.skip()` shows the captured logging).

Comment: To answer my own question: I ended up adding a log handler that only logs records where the msg starts with 'SKIP'

Comment: Official docs reference: [Exclude Feature/Scenario at Runtime | Noteworthy in Version 1.2.5](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html?highlight=skip#exclude-feature-scenario-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the effect you are going after. **If the effect you want is for behave to skip a single step and *only this single step*, then as of version 1.2.5 behave does not provide an API to do this.** If you look in `behave/model.py` you'll see that there are no `skip` and `mark_skipped` methods for the `Step` class. There is no alternate mechanism provided to do this.

**If the effect you want is for behave to mark the step *and* its entire scenario as skipped, then this is possible.** If you are okay with this, then the [answer by Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27258846/1906307) is really what you had to do in behave before 1.2.5: use `before_feature` to scan the scenarios and mark them as skipped before running them. This would effectively mark your step as skipped.

As [m4tx's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589857/1906307), as of behave 1.2.5 you can call `context.scenario.skip` from a step's implementation function to skip the scenario. However, again, this will mark the *entire scenario* as skipped. It is true that the earlier steps will have executed and will have had a chance to fail but when the scenario will appear in the count of skipped scenarios and *all* its steps (including those that may have passed before the step that called `context.scenario.skip`) will appear in the list of skipped steps. Moreover, the steps which follow the step that called `context.scenario.skip` will not execute at all.