# Skip Step Behave Python

Tags: python, python-behave

Is there any option to skip step during an executing scenario in behave (Python). I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Opening and closing driver by clicking and sliding
    When swipe right
    Then drawer should appear
    When swipe left
    Then drawer should disappear
    Given part is for Android # now only Android executes, iOS not
    When click hamburger
    Then drawer should appear
    When click outside drawer
    Then drawer should disappear
```

Right now I have some variable passed with context and I check if tit's true before each step like this:

```
@when('swipe right')
def step_slide_right(context):
    dc = context.device_commands
    if dc.check_if_this_is_the_platform(context.run_test_for):
        dc.slide_right()
```

Is there any function to skip inside `before_step(context,step)` like `skip_step`, to not call `if dc.check_if_this_is_the_platform(context.run_test_for):...` in each step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip a behave step in the step implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504047/skip-a-behave-step-in-the-step-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a `@skip_if` for steps but from what I can tell there is a feature added in 1.2.5 that might work for your purposes. You would outline two scenarios, and tag them `@use.with_os=Android` and `@use.with_os=iOS` (See [Active Tag Logic](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#active-tag-logic)).

```
@use.with_os=Android
Scenario: Opening and closing driver by clicking and sliding
    When swipe right
    Then drawer should appear
    When swipe left
    Then drawer should disappear
    Given part is for Android # now only Android executes, iOS not
    When click hamburger
    Then drawer should appear
    When click outside drawer
    Then drawer should disappear

@use.with_os=iOS
Scenario: Opening and closing driver by clicking and sliding
    When swipe right
    Then drawer should appear
    When swipe left
    Then drawer should disappear
```

Then include `-D os=Android` or `-D os=iOS` on your run command (See [userdata](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#index-7)).

And it will use the scenario tagged for that device.