# python bdd framework: How to execute a code before and after step

Tags: python-3.x, bdd, python-behave, pytest-bdd

I am tyring to implement funtionality before a step and after a step in python

```
Scenario: Addition
        Given Calculator app is run
        When I input "2+3" to calculator
        Then I get result "5"
```

i wish to execute a funtionality before executing second step. How can i proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

The `environment.py` file can be used for this:

`features/environment.py`

```
def before_step(context, step):
    if <some logic to determine which step this is>:
        do_something_before_step()

def after_step(context, step):
    if <some logic to determine which step this is>:
        do_something_after_step()
```

Comment: From the above scenario as i posted how can i implement the logic to skip the second step

Comment: some helpful  info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504047/skip-a-behave-step-in-the-step-implementation I think you can skip right now scenario on condition